# Can't get the URL of the uploaded file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get the URL of the uploaded file, but I get this: `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@a12a0cb` or something similar.

Here is the code I've tried (kotlin):

```js
val uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("content/$uid/$uid.jpg")

storageRef.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapShot ->
    val downloadUrl = storageRef.downloadUrl
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Photos").child(date).push().setValue(downloadUrl)
}
```

But it doesn't work. Also I've tried the following code:

```js
val uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("content/$uid/$uid.jpg")

storageRef.putFile(file).addOnSuccessListener (
      object : OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {
          override fun onSuccess(taskSnapshot: UploadTask.TaskSnapshot?) {
              val downloadUrl = storageRef.downloadUrl
              FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Photos").child(date).push().setValue(downloadUrl)
          }
      }
)
```

But the result is the same. I'm still getting `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@a12a0cb` inserted into my database, instead of the URL. What I'm doing wrong? I've spent all my day trying to figure it out, please help.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I just solved it.
I can not say exactly why it did not work with other syntaxes, but I got the result doing it this way: (Firebase implementation version: 16.0.1 / Kotlin)

```
mReference.putFile (uri) .addOnFailureListener {
          // failure
       } .addOnSuccessListener () {taskSnapshot -> 
         // success
             mReference.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener () {taskSnapshot ->

                 var url = taskSnapshot.result
                 println ("url =" + url.toString ())

             }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a part of the code of my project, which had the same problem of yours, but now working fine after making necessary modifications, make changes accordingly.

```
final StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child(current_user_id + ".jpg");


            filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                String download_url=uri.toString();//Here is the URL

                                mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(download_url)/*Storing the URL in the Firebase database*/
                                 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                            /*mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Success Uploading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }else {
                                /*Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error in uploading!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();*/
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The key point here in getting the download URL is to understand that there are multiple `Task` values that are being used to finally get the actual `Uri`.

The `dbRef.downloadUrl` actually returns a `Task` itself. And we retrieve the Uri of the uploaded file from this `Task`.

Here is a pseudo-code:

```
        val finalStoragePathRef = mStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri!!.lastPathSegment!!)

        //putFile() returns an UploadTask and you can call the listener methods on this task            
        finalStoragePathRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            //Failure
                        }.addOnSuccessListener { //If upload was a success, get the downloadUrl

        //downloadUrl() returns a Task with the Uri
        //Extract the Uri from addOnCompleteListener method of the downloadUrl() method

                            finalStoragePathRef.downloadUrl.addOnCompleteListener {
                                val url = it.result
                                Log.i (TAG, "URL: " + url.toString ())
    //Create your data model
                                val message = Message(...,mUsername,url.toString())
    //Add the data to your database                            
mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(message)
                            }
                        }
```

Hope this makes sense. A lot of the older methods are now deprecated and its best to refer to the documentation to get a better idea:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an old version of Firebase-storage. The way you want to get the URL is deprecated, take a look at the change log [Cloud Storage version 16.0.1](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

I dont have the Kotlin code, but the java code is

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

This code you can find in the Android documentation of [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) in the section Android > Upload Files > Get a download URL

Comment: Can I use older vesion of firebase storage? Ex. 15.0.2? This version is much easier to use, the API is simpler to understand.

Comment: I needed to update my code because i had the same problem as you, suddenly it stop working. Now is a little more complicated to get the downloadURL but is the only way i know. 

I suggest you update because that also bring improvements and bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

This Code worked for me

```
//Data is the uri of the file
  UploadTask uploadTask =mProfileStorageRef.child("profilePic").putFile(data);
 uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

            task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        //Url is here
                        String url = uri.toString();



                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are working with kotlin, this code is based on the official documentation and works like a charm.

```
    fun fileUpload() {


    mFireBaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    mphotoStorageReference = mFireBaseStorage.getReference().child("alvaras")

    //in case you want to compress your bitmap before upload
    val bmp: Bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath) //filepath is the URI from the onActivityResult
    val baos: ByteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, baos) //25 is the compression, cane be anything between 1 and 100, but 100 is no compression

    //get the uri from the bitmap
    val tempUri: Uri = getImageUri(this, bmp)
    //transform the new compressed bmp in filepath uri
    filePath = tempUri //update the filePath variable

var uploadTask = mphotoStorageReference.putFile(filePath)

    val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            task.exception?.let {
                throw it
            }
        }
        return@Continuation mphotoStorageReference.downloadUrl
    }).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val downloadUri = task.result

            urifinal = downloadUri.toString() //this is the url you want
            val imageView: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView1)

            //show it in a imageview with glide with the url
            Glide.with(this@MapsActivity).load(urifinal).into(imageView)
            imageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else {
            // Handle failures
        Toast.makeText(this, "An error occur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            // ...
        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: `val download = task.result` returns a `Task`

Answer (score 0):

**Using Kotlin**

There is a little error in the official doc

but it's corrected [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61061743/7795072)