# download url is getting as com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@441942b : Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

i have checked available resources and yet either i get error or at best i get `com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@5f9a842` as the uri

Following this latest google doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files), i still got the `com.gms` as url

here is my code

```
            val fileRef = storageProfilePicRef!!.child(firebaseUser.uid + "jpg")

            val uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)
            uploadTask.continueWith {
                if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                    pd.dismiss()
                    it.exception?.let { t ->
                        throw t
                    }
                }
                fileRef.downloadUrl
            }.addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val downloadUrl = it.result
                    myUri = downloadUrl.toString()

                    print("Task: ${downloadUrl}")
                    ...
```

**Terminal:** `I/System.out: Task: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@4298dc1(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false`

Comment: The duplicate primarily talks about java, but the underlying issue is the same.  downloadUrl returns a Task, not a URL.  You have to deal with it asynchronously just like the Task returned from putFile.  See also the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: what's the difference between OnCompleteListener and OnSuccesListener ?

Comment: Tried it, still didn't work...pls what is the best way to get the uri after uploading it...?

Comment: The way shown in the documentation.  If you have made a new attempt using what you know already about Tasks (you already used one with putFile), please post a new question showing what you have that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: my code is exactly what is shown here in the firebase doc on how to get download url after uploading

Comment: Did you read the duplicate that I marked to understand what you did wrong?  Did you click through to the documentation link that I provided in the first comment?  If you did either of those things, you would better understand how to proceed.

Comment: @DougStevenson As far as I can see OP **is** calling `getDownloadURL()`, which translates to `downloadUrl` in Kotlin. In fact their code is pretty similar to https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url. I'm not sure why it's printing a serialized `Task`.

Comment: @X-Black... The main difference I see between your code and that in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url) is that you use `it`, while the documentation explicitly declares the `task`. I'd recommend using explicit `task` declarations, as shown in the docs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My mistake.  They're just logging the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !!!**

```
        val fileRef = storageProfilePicRef!!.child(firebaseUser.uid + "jpg")

        val uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)
        uploadTask.continueWith {
            if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                pd.dismiss()
                it.exception?.let { t ->
                    throw t
                }
            }
            fileRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUrl = it.result //Here returns a task..
                myUri = downloadUrl.toString()

                print("Task: ${downloadUrl}")
                ...
```

> `val downloadurl = it.result` returns a `Task`

correct it by adding an `addOnSuccessListener`

**so the correct code is**

```
val uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)
        uploadTask.continueWith {
            if (!it.isSuccessful) {
                pd.dismiss()
                it.exception?.let { t ->
                    throw t
                }
            }
            fileRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                it.result!!.addOnSuccessListener{task ->
                                 myUri = task.toString()
                                print("$myUri")
                                 ...
                                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're logging the wrong value.  Instead of this:

```
print("Task: ${downloadUrl}")
```

Log this:

```
print("Task: ${downloadUrl.result.toString()}")
```

Your `downloadUrl` variable is not correctly named.  It's a Task, not a URL.  It might be clearer like this:

```
val task = it.result
val uri = task.result
val uriAsString = uri.toString()
```

Comment: `val uri = task.result` gives this error ::  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete`

Answer (score 0):

i sloved the problem
you should make
addOnSuccessListener return uri->unit not task

```
}.addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            it.result!!.addOnSuccessListener{uri->unit ->
                             myUri = task.toString()
                            print("$myUri")
                             ...
                                }
```

Comment: then  myuri =uri.toString

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).